# How to define a recursive object with a single expression?

Tags: javascript

For example, given this object:

```
let foo = {foo:1};
let bar = {a:foo,b:foo};
```

We can define `bar` as a single expression by writing it as:

```
let bar = (($0)=>({a:$0={foo:1},b:$0}))()
```

However, given this object:

```
let o = {a:'perfect'};
o.circle = o;
```

Is it possible to recreate the structure of `o` with a single expression?

---

This won't work:

```
(($0)=>($0={a:"perfect",circle:$0}))()
```

Because `circle` is nested and `$0` has been defined yet.

Comment: Would using `Object.assign()` be able to do what you want? I feel like it might.

Comment: `({...$0={a:'perfect'},circle:$0})`. Use `Object.assign` as necessary. I really don't see why you need this.

Comment: @AndrewLi That won't create a reference cycle but just lead to the same result as `{a:'perfect',circle:{a:'perfect'}}`

Comment: @Bergi Oh, I see. They want `circle` also in the `circle` property?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes, I think so. `Object.assign($0={a:'perfect'}, {circle:$0})` could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to solve this with getter properties, an assignment is unavoidable.

There are all kinds of ways to do that, even within a single expression:

```
let o = (o = {a:'perfect'}).circle = o;
```

But I would recommend to focus on clarity and use an IIFE instead:

```
const o = (function(){
    const x = {a:'perfect'};
    x.circle = x;
    return x;
}());
// more like the first solution but without the mutable `o` variable:
const o = (x => x.circle = x)({a:'perfect'});
```